# Updated install.bash for ros-electric-turtlebot's upstart

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am pretty excited to have Turtlebot on Electric! I'm keen to try it on 11.10 at some point, but I'm still using Natty for now.

I've just done the upgrade to ros-electric-turtlebot (finally!) and had an upstart problem along the way. In install.bash, the `chmod`s are pointed at `/usr/bin` (should be `/usr/sbin`), and the `mkdir`s error out if you've already run the script once or otherwise created the stuff in `/etc/ros`.

There are easy fixes for both of these: point the `chmod`s at `/usr/sbin`, and add `-p` to the `mkdir` calls.

Here's my install.bash. Feel free to use it, of course, if it correctly fixes the problems:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run this as root, from the directory containing it!
#
# USAGE: sudo ./install.bash
#  or
# sudo ./install.bash usb0
#
# where usb0 is whatever network interface you want to set the robot
# up for.  wlan0 is the default.

interface=wlan0

if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
        interface=$1
    fi
fi

echo "Installing using network interface $interface."

sed "s/wlan0/$interface/g" < turtlebot-start > /usr/sbin/turtlebot-start
chmod +x /usr/sbin/turtlebot-start
sed "s/wlan0/$interface/g"  /usr/sbin/turtlebot-stop
chmod +x /usr/sbin/turtlebot-stop
sed "s/wlan0/$interface/g"  /etc/init/turtlebot.conf

# Copy files into /etc/ros/electric/turtlebot
mkdir -p /etc/ros
mkdir -p /etc/ros/electric
cat turtlebot.launch > /etc/ros/electric/turtlebot.launch

echo '. /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash; export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/turtlebot/ros:${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}' > /etc/ros/setup.bash
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11680/updated-install.bash-for-ros-electric-turtlebot%27s-upstart/) by [Alaina](https://answers.ros.org/users/767/alaina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2011-11-04

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The /sbin has already been fixed in trunk, and will soon be in debs (we had some delays due to spinning up for Oneric). I just added the mkdir -p, thanks.

In the future, things that are clearly a bug/defect are best posted as a ticket on the appropriate Trac instance (for turtlebot, that is https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac)

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-12-06**:
Yes, this should be in current debs

**Comment by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on 2011-12-06**:
Can I ask has this been added to the debs yet?